# Why is True in Visual Basic stored as -1?

Tags: vb.net

It seems like many languages, including C/C++ and Java, have both a Logical Not (which converts 0 to 1 and vice-versa) and a Bitwise Not (bitwise inversion AKA one's complement). In Visual Basic, `Not` is simply bitwise, and `True` has the value -1. Is there any particular reason VB was implemented this way?

If it's some vestige carried over from BASIC, then does it represent a change in thinking between 1964 (BASIC) and the time of later languages like C (1972)?

Comment: -1 is all 1's which is not 0 (0 being false), depends on language the presentation is different, in python I believe it stores truth as 1.  You should never compare to a number when checking boolean value, because binary representation varies from language to language, but as long as it is not zero, most languages will understand that both 1 and -1 are True once you tell them that the value represents boolean.

Comment: Just realized my previous comment may not be answering your question, because it does not really answer why they chose to store truth as -1, but left it as it may explain why that shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just speculation, but the bit-wise AND/OR/NOT was probably chosen (in the days of 8-bit BASIC implementations) for sake of easier implementation and flexibility over zero-vs-nonzero logic.

You couldn't make the language too complicated, as this was back in the "home computer" days when CPU cycles were in kilo-hertz, and memory was in kilo-bytes, and storage devices where rare or expensive or primative (such as a paper tape reader or hastily adapted cassette recorder/player).

Dartmouth BASIC (the start of it all, c 1964, http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_4th_Edition_Jan68.pdf), didn't even have AND/OR/NOT, not even as keywords for IF.

However, as far as BASIC from Microsoft goes, the start of that is with Altair BASIC (c 1975, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_BASIC). Altair BASIC has AND/OR/NOT (https://ia601600.us.archive.org/35/items/bitsavers_mitsMITSAl_6669937/MITS_AltairBASIC_1975.pdf), described as "LOGICAL AND BITWISE" (pg 27 - pg 31 of PDF). It would be with Altair BASIC that False/True mapped to 0/-1; and that the THEN clause is executed for any non-zero expression of IF. This apparently is what set the idiom for later versions.

(Side note, I have no idea if their "INTRUDER ALERT" example really worked, but it does not seem right to me.)

Anyway, as AND/OR/NOT were operators that worked on integers, it would have been straightforward work to add them to their expression parser/evaluator code. Adding additional operators for zero-vs-nonzero might have been an expensive idea given the single-digit kilobyte memory capacity at the time. Short-circuit AND/OR/NOT would involve jumps, making the expression parser/evaluator a more involved design.

Since `NOT 0` is `-1` (all bits set to 1, and interpreted in the two's complement sense), that in itself would necessitate -1 as the standard for True (so that the "LOGICAL" aspect would work as expected).

You'll note that VB.NET is merely keeping to that legacy idiom (as did VB6 which it replaced), but it's only an issue whenever you make it cast to Integer. But as Hans Passant has indicated, VB.NET has evolved from there.

Comment: Excellent research.  I'd add wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Characteristics opines on this and looks to be based on https://www.scribd.com/document/196416591/Learning-With-Visual-Basic-6-0-to-Telecommunication-Engineering and speaks of "being related to the characteristics of CPU instructions at the time"

Answer (score 6):

There's history, BASIC also did not have a distinction between the logical and bitwise AND and OR operator.  `Not` does both jobs in VB.NET, it is a logical NOT if the operand is a Boolean and a bitwise negation if the operand is numerical.

True converts to -1 primarily to allow the `And` and `Or` operators to produce a logical expression result.  So, say, `True And 2` is still true and matches `True And CBool(2)`, that wouldn't work if True converts to 1.  The missing short-circuiting behavior was a fairly serious deficiency in old VB versions and inspired the addition of AndAlso and OrElse.

Comment: The missing short-circuiting behavior is still a fairly serious deficiency in  VBA :'(

Comment: VB.Net originally had `BitAnd` and `BitOr` for doing bitwise operations, but then they added `AndAlso` and `OrElse` and made `And` and `Or` the operators to use for bitwise operations.

Comment: @Blackhawk In VBA/VB6, it is possible to do short-circuiting behavior via `Select Case True` (in place of its equivalent `If ... Then`).

Comment: While I agree that this is relevant, I think it's equivalent to saying that all the Boolean operators in VB are bitwise.

Comment: In VB6/VBA short circuiting does not need a `Select` statement, simply break the composite `If` statement into two If statements one nested within the other (which I think is quite readable).